# jquery mascara formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou tentando fazer uma validaçao no campo de formulario utilizando jquery, caso o tamanho for maior que numero de cpf ele colocar a mascara  de cnpj nesse mesmo campo

```
 var tamanho = $('.cpfcnpj').length;
    if (tamanho == 11){
        $(".cpfcnpj").mask('000.000.000-00',{reverse: true});
        alert("teste");
        }
    else if(tamanho > 12){
        $(".cpfcnpj").mask('00.000.000/0000-00',{reverse: true});
        alert("dois");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz `$('.cpfcnpj').val()`, ele traz o texto todo por completo, inclusive os pontos e traços. Ou seja, contará o tamanho errado.

Eis a maneira correta de se fazer isso e também como está documentado no próprio plugin: [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```
var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12 ? '000.000.000-009' : '00.000.000/0000-00';
},
spOptions = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
      field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
    }
};

$('.akira').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
```

Comment: Realmente vou estudar mais essa funçao mas foi o que resolveu

Answer (score 2):

Se queres obter o valor de dentro do `.cpfcnpj`, tens que utilizar [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Ao fazeres isto - `$('.cpfcnpj').length;`, ele retorna o número de elementos com a class `.cpfcnpj`.

```
var tamanho = $('.cpfcnpj').val();
if (tamanho.length == 11) {
    $(".cpfcnpj").mask('000.000.000-00',{reverse: true});
    alert("teste");
}
else if (tamanho.length > 12) {
    $(".cpfcnpj").mask('00.000.000/0000-00',{reverse: true});
    alert("dois");
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/1tzhm01z/

> Podes ler mais sobre o `.val()` aqui neste link: [jQuery API Documentation .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: sim mas ele nao aplica a mascara ...

Comment: qual é o plugin que estás a usar?

Comment: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ esse daqui

Comment: @RobertoAraujo no link que você enviou está lá documentado como você pode fazer isso. Entrando nesse link do plugin, navegue até as secções: **On-the-fly mask change** e **Mask as a function** nos exemplos de código, estão lá dois trechos de código exatamente com isso que você quer fazer.