# Widget para introduzir data e hora

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou a utilizar o `jQuery` e o `jQuery UI` no front-end da minha aplicação web. Com o `jQuery UI` posso utilizar o widget `datepicker` (que só dá para introduzir data, segundo me parece...), e tenho-o utilizado noutras aplicações e até nesta.

No entanto, eu para uma nova função da minha app precisava de incluir um campo que desse para introduzir data e hora. Existe algum widget nestas livrarias para introduzir a data e a hora? É preciso uma nova livraria?

EDIT:
Estou a utilizar versões recentes do `jQuery` e do `jQuery UI`...

Comment: um input do tipo date? ou se quer mascara? pergunta fala esclarecimentos?

Comment: Sim um input tipo date. Seria do tipo "datetime",...

Comment: então já tem?...

Comment: `$("#datepicker").datepicker()` só dá para data! Vi https://api.jqueryui.com/category/widgets/ e não tinha qualquer coisa como datetimepicker... Se tem uma solução mostrava-me o código ou o link?

Comment: Por exemplo o `HTML` tem o `<input type="datetime-local" />` que dá para isso. No entanto o aspecto, e mesmo a funcionalidade não é o mesmo de browser para browser. Por exemplo, no Firefox 81 a implementação não me parece aceitável... O que queria era uma livraria para isto, de modo a ser uniforme de browser para browser. Os utilizadores da minha app podem ter browsers antigos...

Comment: Mais: o `HTML` `<input type="datetime" />` está a tornar-se obsoleto... Ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime por exemplo

Comment: Você quer um exemplo input com máscara?

Comment: Parece-me que esse exemplo é introduzir a data como texto... O que eu queria era uma coisa mais user-friendly... que o utilizador gostasse... Mas se só tem esse, força...

Comment: No site tem vários exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99138/jquery-mascara-formulario outra https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128295/mascara-moeda-jquery outra https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168967/problema-com-mascara-em-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por utilizar o `jquery` e o `jQuery UI`.
Assim criei controles no código `HTML` como o seguinte:

```
<input class="font-md" type="text" id="datepicker" name="ausData" value="" autocomplete="off" />

<input class="font-md" type="time" id="timepicker" name="ausDataT" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

e incluí o seguinte script na página:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

O `input#datepicker` é um input que permite escolher a data num calendário, depois de activado com o script acima. O `input#timepicker` permite inserir a hora e a sua interface depende do browser onde está a ser utilizado. Por exemplo, no Firefox insere-se texto conforme uma certa máscara; no Edge abre-se um menu que permite escolher a hora.

Incluí o `jQuery` e `jQuery UI` com as seguintes tags:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-rByPlHULObEjJ6XQxW/flG2r+22R5dKiAoef+aXWfik=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```